# How to patch assembly code to the end of exe file

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm trying to patch code written in x86 Assembly to an end of the file given as a parameter.

specific in my code:

the function `code_start` prints a message to stdout.

the function `code_end` purpose is to patch the code from `code_start` to the end of a file name given as a parameter from the C program.

My question is:

What should I fill (where I put the question marks) or change in the function `code_end` in the order it to work as I wish.
My idea was to open the file by an append system call, write the function `code_start`, close the file.

**important note: without using any imported functions, only by using system calls**

Code snippet:

```
code_start:

    pushad
    mov eax,4   ;system call number (sys_write)            
    mov ebx,1   ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov ecx, msg    ;message to write
    mov edx, len    ;message length   
    int 0x80    ;call kernel
    popad
    ret

code_end:
    push ebp             ; Save caller state
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 4          ; Leave space for local var on stack
    pushad                  ; Save some more caller state

    mov eax,4   ;system call number (sys_write)          
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]    ; Copy function args to registers: leftmost -> fileName  
    mov ecx, 1024   ;system call number O_APPEND
    int 0x80    ;call kernel

    ;eax has the pointer to end of file

    mov ebx, eax ;move the file pointer to second argument
    mov eax, 4 ;move the code of SYS_WRITE 
    mov ecx, ?? ;from where to write 
    mov edx, ?? ;how much to write
    int 0x80    ;call kernel

    mov eax,6   ;system call number (SYS_CLOSE)          
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]    ; Copy function args to registers: leftmost -> fileName 
    int 0x80    ;call kernel

    popad
    add esp, 4
    pop     ebp ; Restore caller state
    ret
```

Comment: It appears that you already have everything you need, since you appear to know the parameters (since they are in `code_start`). So what do you want to write? That goes in `ecx`. How big is it? That goes in `edx`. You sort of knew that already, seeing as you already did it in `code_start`. Just do it again.

Comment: yes, I know that those parameters goes to `ecx` and `edx` but I don't know what should I place in those registers in order ro write the `code_start` function to the given file.

Comment: You don't seem to be listening to yourself. You say you want to write the bytes of the `code_start` function, so that's the thing you want to write, which goes in `ecx`.

Comment: I think I understand now, do you mean to place the label of `code_start` in `ecx`, and in `edx` the result of subtraction of the label `code_end` minus `code_start`?  if so, it's still does't work properly. I'm trying to figure out now why, if you have any advise I'll be grateful.

Comment: Run your program under `strace ./my_prog` to trace the system calls you make, decoding actual args and return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all instead of: `mov ecx 1024` it should be `mov ecx, 1025` in order to open it for write and appeand.
Second instead of the question marks it should be:
`mov ecx, code_start`
`mov edx code_end`
`sub edx, code_start`